# How to display data from end date using interval of 3 days?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

i have to some entry in database to send notification to user but conditions is look like this,

here my end date is `06-05-2019` and now current date is `03-05-2019` or `01-05-2019` and i want to send notification before 3 days of end date to actual end date. Like, my end date is `06-05-2019` of some event then i want to sent notification on dates `04-05-2019`, `05-05-2019`, `06-05-2019`.

My cakePHP query code is here :

````
$offer_notify_second = $this->NotificationStore->find('all', array(
                'contain' => array(),          
                'fields' => array('NotificationStore.id','NotificationStore.role_id','NotificationStore.user_id','NotificationStore.notification_type','NotificationStore.notification_app_display_type','NotificationStore.link','NotificationStore.offer_id','NotificationStore.offer_type'), 
                'conditions' => array('DATE_SUB(NotificationStore.end_date, INTERVAL 3 DAY)' => date('Y-m-d'), 'NotificationStore.user_id' => $this->request->data['user_id'], 'NotificationStore.notification_type' => OFFER_NOTIFICATION),
            ));
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will share raw query snippet, you can map it to CAKEPHP

```
WHERE NotificationStore.end_date >= DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 3 DAY) + INTERVAL 0 SECOND  AND NotificationStore.end_date >= CURDATE();
```

Part 1

```
NotificationStore.end_date >= DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 3 DAY) + INTERVAL 0
```

It means, NOW + 3 days should be greater than end date
e.g.

current is 2019-05-02 and next 3 days is 2019-05-05 then condition fails
current is 2019-05-03 and next 3 days is 2019-05-06 then condition succeed

Part 2

```
NotificationStore.end_date >= CURDATE()
```

It means, end_date must be greater than cur_date to satisfy upcoming 3 days range otherwise it will be always greater with first condition.